# Отслеживать изменение роута

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Необходимо, чтобы с определенного экрана нельзя было уйти, пока не завершишь, например, сделку. То есть в роутере прописано /action/:actionId - ActionProcessComponent. Но пользователь может нажать браузерную кнопку назад и выйти по сути из сделки. А хотелось бы, чтобы при изменении роута запрещать это и возвращать обратно на ActionProcessComponent. Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Может вызвать `next(false)` в хуке [`beforeRouteLeave`](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#хуки-дnя-конкретных-компонентов)

Comment: А хук этот указывать в компоненте, или в маршрутах?

Comment: ⁠В⁠ к⁠о⁠м⁠п⁠о⁠н⁠е⁠н⁠т⁠е

Comment: Работает! Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример кода(писать в компонент):

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  next(
    confirm('Данные не сохранены. Точно перейти?')
  )
}
```

Рабочий пример [ТУТ](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/aagNgG?editors=1010).

Comment: совсем не по теме ответ то. и в данном случае это событие вообще не сработает

Comment: Я так понял не работает из-за того что spa (не поддерживает history и hash режимы)

Comment: Вариант пользователя diraria сработал идеально. Спасибо!